# How to create a menu on click of GameObject? (Unity)

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, menu, mouseover

I want to be able to hover over a GameObject (agent) and on either right or left click, create a floating menu similar to the windows right click menu. I have tried using a combination of OnGUI() and OnMouseOver() but I either don't get the behaviour I need or get nothing at all. Here is what I have so far:

```
private void OnMouseOver()
{
    mouseOver = true;
    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
}

private void OnMouseExit()
{
    mouseOver = false;
}

private void OnGUI()
{

    if (mouseOver && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 200f, 100f), "this is a test");
    }
}
```

mouseOver and mousePos are initialy set to false.

Comment: Have you added a collider to the object you wish to hover over?

Comment: I didn't know that Input.GetMouseButtonDown() only executes for a single frame, so the menu was appearing but only for that one frame. I fixed the issue by replacing it with Input.GetMouseButton() which executes for as long as the button is pressed

Answer (score 2):

Input.GetMouseButtonDown() only executes for a single frame so the GUI.Box is being drawn but only for a single frame.

To fix this Input.GetMouseButton() can be used instead as it executes for as long as the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create my desired menu in a Canvas, add an animator controller and an animation and put it outside of the camera view (the animation moves the menu inside the camera view), finally add a bool condition trigger to hide or show the menu

[image]

Then i just attach a click function into a button to fire the animation when somebody clicks it

```
public class ShowMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator ObjectBtnAnimations;

    public void HideObjControls()
    {
        if (ObjectBtnAnimations.GetBool("hide"))
        {
            ObjectBtnAnimations.SetBool("hide", false);
        }
        else
        {
            ObjectBtnAnimations.SetBool("hide", true);
        }
    }
}
```